# ALV column titles i18n?

Tags: abap, alv

I want to translate the text columns of an ALV-Grid into different languages.

For example I have following code:

```
alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'REVENUE' )->set_short_text( 'Revenue' ) ##NO_TEXT.
alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'REVENUE' )->set_medium_text( 'Revenue ) ##NO_TEXT.
alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'REVENUE' )->set_long_text( 'Revenue' ) ##NO_TEXT.
```

My idea was to use text elements to translate the column names.

```
alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'REVENUE' )->set_short_text( TEXT-001 ) ##NO_TEXT.
alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'REVENUE' )->set_medium_text( TEXT-002 ) ##NO_TEXT.
alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'REVENUE' )->set_long_text( TEXT-003 ) ##NO_TEXT.
```

But I'm not a fan of maintaining 3 different text elements.

Is there a better solution for this issue?

Comment: create a ddic reference to any field (`set_ddic_reference`) or use the data element directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best option is creating your own data element and managing translation on there.